# Resignation during Probation - Notice or no Notice

Tags: resignation, notice-period, probation

I am one month into a 3 month probationary period with my employer.

Since this is a time for each of us to consider the fit for the position, I have come to the conclusion this particular employer is not a good fit for me.

The handbook states the employer can dismiss the employee at any time for no reason during the probationary period, with or without notice.

Does the same hold true if I as an employee wish to exit?  Notice required?

Comment: which country is this

Answer (score 4):

> The handbook states the employer can dismiss the employee at any time
>   for no reason during the probationary period, with or without notice.
>   Does the same hold true if I as an employee wish to exit? Notice
>   required?

That depends on your locale, local laws, your contract, and the company culture.

If the employer is free to fire you at any time during probation with no notice, then I would assume that you are free to do the same and leave with no notice.

All of the contracts with probation periods that I have seen work that way.

Comment: It is indeed very locale-specific. For example, here in Bulgaria, the employer can fire you with no notice, while the contract usually specifies you need to give one (between one and three months). Whether you need to serve the full period, though, is something you can negotiate with the employer. This is not the default case the law dictates, but it is the defacto scenario.